# Trouble with rewrite and redirect using .htaccess to make pretty URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make pretty/SEO-friendly URLs for my project but I can't properly configure .htaccess file.

I learned how to rewrite and redirect from `%domain%/profile.php` to `%domain%/profile` so existing bookmarks will work and there won't be duplicate pages for search engines. It works fine with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/profile\.php$
RewriteRule .* /profile [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^profile$ /profile.php [L]
```

But I can't figure out how to make it with parameters, like `%domain%/profile.php?id=1` to `%domain%/profile/1`.
Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id=([0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^profile\.php?id=([0-9]*)$ /profile/%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]*)$ /profile.php?id=%1 [L]
```

But instead of `%domain%/profile/1` server returns `profile?id=1`.

Comment: can you try `RewriteRule ^profile\.php\?id=([0-9]*)$ /profile/%1 [R=301,L]`  (since question mark is a special character for regex in rewrite)

Comment: check this https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, [Nikos M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3591273/nikos-m)

Also, [htaccess Tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) can help a lot.

Since we're already checked for ?id=[0-9] in %{QUERY_STRING} it's enough to check for profile.php only in pattern. Also I added question mark in substitute link so I get `/profile/1` instead of `/profile/1?id=1`.

```
RewriteRule ^profile\.php?id=([0-9]*)$ /profile/%1 [R=301,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^profile\.php$ /profile/%1? [R=301,L]
```

It works fine now.